# Is this use of macros in C portable?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

This C language program defines macros START and END which generate runtime function execution information. The actions TRACE_START and TRACE_END could be anything of course e.g. pushing and popping stacks, dynamic profiling etc. Furthermore there is no reason why the action behaviour could not be runtime configurable. This offers many attractive possibilities for certain types of software product.

On the downside, redefining the opening and closing braces of functions from f(){} to f()START...END would likely break many automatic tools. **Accepting that this is the case**,
what are the implications of doing this? Is this use of the macro processor portable?

The code below compiles correctly with gcc --pedantic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START           {TRACE_START
#define END             TRACE_END}
#define TRACE_START     printf("ENTERING %s\n", __func__);
#define TRACE_END       printf("LEAVING %s\n", __func__);

int func()
START
    printf ("Hello World %s\n");
END

int main()
START
    func();
END
```

and produces the output

```
ENTERING main
ENTERING func
Hello World
LEAVING func
LEAVING main
```

Thank-you in advance for your insightful comments.

Comment: The preprocessor isn't supposed to care about the syntax of the results of its expansions, and the compiler isn't supposed to care about what preprocessor magic produced its input.  AFAIK this is perfectly legal, albeit horrible.

Comment: The code as-is is *strictly conforming* as the C standard defines it, so it is portable in that sense. As you note, it may not work with automatic tools. It also cannot be relied to work with other source code in general, as other source code might have its own uses for `START`, `END`, and so on. As you progress as a programmer, you will generally learn to avoid kludges like this. There is little reason to remove the `{` and `}`. Routines could be instrumented simply by putting the `START` and `END` macros with the `{` and `}` instead of in place of them.

Comment: Note there is no reason to expect that an arbitrary function will ever reach the `END`, as functions may return with `return` statements (or with `longjmp` or `exit` or `abort`, and others).

Comment: Non-void functions are even required to not reach the `END`.

Comment: It is "portable" in the sense that every standard-conforming compiler must accept it. It is, however, highly **unconventional** and, as you noted, will likely interact poorly with IDEs, code analysis tools, code formatters, and other human beings who try to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this use of macros in C portable?

Yes.

> what are the implications of doing this?

The implication of these tools(? what tools?) being broken is that they may stop working and require patching or some work. Most probably, "these tools" should be fixed, so they are not affected by such constructs.

> Is this use of the macro processor portable?

Yes.